# Bash prompt when my home directory is a symbolic link

Tags: bash, directory, symlink, prompt, home

I symlinked my `/host/Users/Kevin` folder to `/home/Kevin`. I also edit the `/etc/passwd` file to `/home/Kevin`. I logged out and logged back in, however when I open up a terminal it's a bash prompt like so:

```
kevin@ubuntu:/host/Users/Kevin$
```

But when I `cd` or `echo $HOME` it changes to:

```
kevin@ubuntu:~$
```

or when I `echo $HOME` it prints `/home/Kevin`.  How can I make it open up in this format by default?

Comment: IIRC this is a limitation of bash, zsh is more clever when the home directory is a symlink. Consider switching to zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put:

```
cd $HOME
```

in your `.bash_profile`, maybe, or your `.bashrc` (the latter executes for every shell, the former only for your login shell). The problem, of course, is that anything that walks the filesystem to find your current directory location is going to find `/host/Users/Kevin folder to /home/Kevin` instead of `/home/Kevin`.

Instead of symlinking, you could:

```
mkdir /home/Kevin
mount -o bind /host/Users/Kevin /home/Kevin
```

This will make `/home/Kevin` a "real" filesystem path (as opposed to one you get to by way of a symlink).  You can add this mount to your `/etc/fstab` if you like.

Comment: Don't put it in `.bashrc`, it would be disruptive when you start a shell in another directory.

Comment: Maybe.  I mentioned that as a possibility because sometimes things are configured (e.g., under X or in OS X terminal) such that putting it into `.profile` or equivalent won't do the right thing, and I'm too lazy to test it out...

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correct that you always want it printed like:

`kevin@ubuntu:/host/Users/Kevin$`

that's simple: edit the file `.bashrc` in your home-directory.
usually you'll find a line like this (or maybe more then one):

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`

replace the `\w` with `$PWD` and save.

Comment: I want it always printed out like: kevin@ubuntu:~$

Comment: - sorry, wasn't really clear from your question which format you really want. in this case, larsks answer is better.